# kubectl run command is failing with a connection refused error

Tags: kubernetes

I am following the hellonode tutorial on kubernetes.io

http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/

I am getting an error when trying to do the 'Create your pod' section.

When I run this command (replacing PROJECT_ID with the one I created) I get the following:

```
$ kubectl run hello-node --image=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/hello-node:v1 --port=8080

The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I get a similar error just typing kubectl version:

```
$ kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.2", GitCommit:"528f879e7d3790ea4287687ef0ab3f2a01cc2718", GitTreeState:"clean"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I'm not sure what to do since I have no experience with kubernetes other than following the steps of this tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the issue.
In the `Create your cluster` section I missed a critical step.

The step I missed was:  `Please ensure that you have configured kubectl to use the cluster you just created.` The configured part is a link to how to do this:

The steps are as follows:

```
gcloud config set project PROJECT
gcloud config set compute/zone ZONE
gcloud config set container/cluster CLUSTER_NAME
gcloud container clusters get-credentials CUSTER_NAME
```

Comment: hi, I had the same issue but  could not solve it by following this. Still it gives the same error.  The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port? Will there be any other reason for this ?