# kubectl : connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am on the way of installing minkube 0.19.1 in Ubuntu 16.04 following the kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/). As prerequisits I have installed kubectl and Oracle VirtualBox.
When I check kubectl with `kubectl version` it gives following.

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.6", GitCommit:"7fa1c1756d8bc963f1a389f4a6937dc71f08ada2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-06-16T18:34:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

But when I netstat the port to check the process it gives nothing for the results.
I have setup Google cloud SDK as well.

I have searched  and tried for many solutions inclusing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845569/kubectl-run-command-is-failing-with-a-connection-refused-error) but was not able to resolve my issue.

Here are my gcloud config and info results.

---

```
$gcloud config list


[compute]
zone = asia-southeast1-a
[core]
account = userName@mail.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = sampleproject1990
```

---

```
$gcloud info


Google Cloud SDK [159.0.0]

Platform: [Linux, x86_64] ('Linux', 'userName', '4.8.0-54-generic', '#57~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 24 16:22:28 UTC 2017', 'x86_64', 'x86_64')
Python Version: [2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]]
Python Location: [/usr/bin/python2]
Site Packages: [Disabled]

Installation Root: [/home/userName/products/google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  kubectl: []
  core: [2017.06.09]
  gcloud: []
  gsutil: [4.26]
  bq: [2.0.24]
  alpha: [2017.03.24]
System PATH: [PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/home/userName/bin:/home/userName/.local/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin]
Python PATH: [/home/userName/products/./google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party:/home/userName/products/google-cloud-sdk/lib:/usr/lib/python2.7/:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [False]
Kubectl on PATH: [/usr/local/bin/kubectl]

WARNING: There are old versions of the Google Cloud Platform tools on your system PATH.
  /usr/local/bin/kubectl

Installation Properties: [/home/userName/products/google-cloud-sdk/properties]
User Config Directory: [/home/userName/.config/gcloud]
Active Configuration Name: [my-configuration]
Active Configuration Path: [/home/userName/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_my-configuration]

Account: [userName@mail.com]
Project: [sampleproject1990]

Current Properties:
  [core]
    project: [sampleproject1990]
    account: [userName@mail.com]
    disable_usage_reporting: [False]
  [compute]
    zone: [asia-southeast1-a]

Logs Directory: [/home/userName/.config/gcloud/logs]
Last Log File: [/home/userName/.config/gcloud/logs/2017.06.21/12.39.23.391849.log]

git: [git version 2.7.4]
ssh: [OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016]
```

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this issue ?

Comment: If you're trying to run `minikube`, the `gcloud` results shouldn't matter, right? Also, what does `minikube status` show?

Comment: I had similar issues with Minikube and virtualbox driver. Please ensure the interface to which the virtualbox is configured, is up . I did a **sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 up** and my issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with Minikube and virtualbox driver. Please ensure the interface to which the virtualbox is configured, is up . 
I did a **`sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 up`** and my issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Turns out that I was running the command without being the root user. So, if you login as the super user (sudo -i), it might work.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is because the Kubelet is not running or is not healthy.

One way to resolve this issue:

```
$ sudo swapoff -a
$ sudo systemctl enable kubelet
$ sudo systemctl start kubelet
```

After this, deploy `Kubernetes` with `kubeadm` as given below:

```
$ sudo kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=all
```

After loading the kubeadm credentials, untaint the master node and join worker nodes if you are working on a cluster.

And now give the command:

```
$ sudo kubectl cluster-info
```

The server and the client should be running with the same Kubernetes version.

If this solution doesn't work, scrape Kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm and kubelet and follow the **Kubernetes installation steps alone** from [this](https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-kubernetes/latest/deployment-guide.html) guide.