# How to connect local kubernetes with local jenkins

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, kind

My kubernetes environment is running on kind while my jenkins environment is running as a docker instance. I tried watching all of the youtube tutorial regarding this and have followed all of the steps carefully but still, I can't seem to get past this very specific error. This error doesn't appear to any of the youtube tutorial I watched and it's very frustrating.

`Error testing connection https://127.0.0.1:53883: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:53883`

The URL is from running the command: kubectl cluster-info

Comment: copy and paste the error instead of an image

Comment: Need more information. What kind or error? Use `netstat -tulpn` command to check that actually the kind k8s is running on that port. Also, the origin of request must have the permission to access the port and the local host.

Comment: What is the result of `kubectl version`? Similar to this post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44669284/18667225